# [rabbitmq]: consumer stop receiving messages after first message

Tags: rabbitmq

I've a nestjs application and a rabbitmq (single) instance in AWS.
The application is deployed in a k8s cluster.

Suddenly the application stopped consuming messages and I can see the messages stuck in the queue.

The same code is deployed in another environment and works fine.
From the rabbit dashboard I cannot see anything can help in figure out what's going on.

It's seems everything is working fine.

I purged the queue, close the connection. What can I do more? Where can I find useful information?